# UITableview cell and header spacing

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

My uitableview header looks like this

[image: header has a transparent area and my cell starting after the image. I want to add a minus margin to my cell]

It has a transparent area. every cell has a header for information.
i want to add a style to my cell. Can i add a style like css "margin-top:-5px;"

Answer (score 1):

Just make the header view smaller than the `UIImageView` you put inside it and be sure that the header's `clipToBounds` and `opaque` properties are set to `NO`.
If you want to specify this in a more elegant manner you can define a .xib for it and put `NSLayoutConstraint`s that satisfy that style command.